# Why I can't create historical Interactions (with a date in the past) And I can't add new facets to already existing interactions

Tags: xdb, xconnect, interaction

**1. Can't add new interaction with historical date**

This is the only way to add new interaction problematically

> ```
> new Interaction(contact, InteractionInitiator, channelId, userAgent);
> ```

and as you can see, I can't provide the `CreationDate` or the `LastModified` date.

I believe this is due to Auditing reasons but at the same time we have a lot of other operations, aside from the happy scenario in production. like(performance testing, Integration testing, demos, ...etc.) this is not acceptable by today's standards.

**2. Can't Edit interaction facets**

If you ever tried to get an already existing interaction to add some new facet to it. you will face this error.

> ```
> { "Message": "Facets cannot be added to existing interaction" }
> ```

e.g. Try to get interaction by id `client.GetAsync` then `client.SetFacet<IpInfo>` then `client.SubmitAsync()` when the interaction in the db doesn't have this facet.

Is there is any reason why I can't do this simple operation?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you on? I think Universal Tracker was made for exactly your scenario. You can set StartDate and similar properties of interaction before sending it to XConnect which is what you need IMO. Check this documentation -> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/universal-tracker.html

Answer (score 2):

Updating interaction facets is definitely something that has been discussed but at the current time it is a product decision to keep these consistent. If you wish to 'change' the value of an interaction, you need to delete the existing one and create a new one. (This leads to the next problem where you cannot currently delete a single interaction via the API). At the time of writing, no version of the xConnect API supports an atomic interaction delete.

As for specifying a time of an event, you will want to use code like the following:

```
//Instantiate the interaction details
var interaction = new Interaction(contact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, channelId, userAgent);

//Create a timestamp (myDateTimeValue being something you have passed in to your method)
var interactionTimestamp = myDateTimeValue.HasValue? myDateTimeValue.Value : DateTime.UtcNow;

//Create the event with your custom time
var xConnectEvent = new Goal(Guid.Parse(goalId), interactionTimestamp);

//Add the event to the interaction
interaction.Events.Add(xConnectEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

When contact interacts with a brand/medium/organization, either online or offline, that particular action or point is known as Interaction. In Sitecore, Interactions are represented by the `Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction` class and must have at least one event. When you create an interaction, you need to pass `ChannelId`, `Initiator`and `UserAgent` mandatory properties into the constructor. `VenueId` and `CampaignId` are the optional properties for the interaction.

Now coming to your questions, **It is not possible to update an interaction once it has been submitted to xConnect**. You can only update the contacts, see the link for update contacts - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/update-contacts.html.
Since every Interaction must have at least one event, so an interaction’s `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`, and `Duration` are calculated using the interaction’s event timestamps and duration. So when you add new interaction problematically, you need to define at least one event and you can pass the `StartDateTime` in that event. This event could be a Goal, outcome or PageViewEvent see the link for adding interaction event - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/add-interaction-events.html